# Can't call a custom method on a controller from AJAX

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am trying to call a controller function from an AJAX call. The view loads from the same controller, but I'm not able to call the function.

Here is the controller code:

```
//  This function will get ajax call where pass two variables and a method name doSomeAction  
class Posts extends \Core\Controller 
{
    public function addNewAction()
    {
        View::renderTemplate('Posts/addnew.html', [
            // 'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }

    public function doSomeAction()
    {
        echo "here";
        // your action code ....
    }
}
```

Here is my Ajax script call function

```
<script>
$(".submitcontr").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'POST/doSomeAction',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: 'value'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Failed to parse question.

Comment: @JonStirling i am trying to call function from controller function doSomeAction(); from view using ajax, the first code is for php and second is for ajax request!

Comment: I'm curious what `url: 'POST/doSomeAction'` is intended to do; keep in mind that raw HTML/JS has no concept of what PHP controller was used/loaded. Instead, you'd need to change your URL to the _route_ that points to doSomeAction (and if you're intending to POST, add `method: 'POST',` to your ajax configuration object)

Comment: You need another php function that will pick up the ajax values, process the request (via your class) then return the data. The url: 'POST/doSomeAction', needs to change to url: 'myAJAXcall.php',

Comment: @ChrisForrence can you please explain what changes do i have to made, i have set apache conf file to the public folder of my app so by default app public folder is accessable!

Comment: can you open that url in a browser tab, the server doesn't know anything about AJAX, the request still has to be a valid request.  In otherwords you should be able to put the same URL right in the browser and get something other then a 404 error.

Comment: i have changed URL to url : '/App/Controllers/Post/dosome', and now it's saying route not matched instead of calling function